# rosserial_arduino catkin_make error: unparsed argument: Port;/dev/ttyACM0

Tags: rosserial, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get the rosserial_arduino tutorial to work ([tutorial here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/CMake)).

The only change I made was to change the board type from "leonardo" to "OpenCR" since I want to use the Robotis OpenCR board.

The execution of `catkin_make helloworld_firmware_hello` gives me the following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/rosserial_arduino/arduino-cmake/cmake/Platform/Arduino.cmake:2073 (message):
  unparsed argument: Port;/dev/ttyACM0
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/rosserial_arduino/arduino-cmake/cmake/Platform/Arduino.cmake:739 (error_for_unparsed)
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/rosserial_arduino/arduino-cmake/cmake/Platform/Arduino.cmake:459 (parse_generator_arguments)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (generate_arduino_firmware)
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem before?

My ROS-noetic install is from yesterday, so everything should be up to date.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384220/rosserial_arduino-catkin_make-error:-unparsed-argument:-port;/dev/ttyacm0/) by [jonasfovea](https://answers.ros.org/users/80765/jonasfovea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think `/dev/ttyACM0` does not exist.

Without connecting the Arduino to the machine running ROS, `/dev/ttyACM0` will not appear. Also, depending on the Arduino, it may have a different name, such as `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

#### UPDATE

I watched the tutorial. I think you're making a typo.

Did you type the semicolon incorrectly?

`Port;/dev/ttyACM0` -> `PORT /dev/ttyACM0`

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jonasfovea](https://answers.ros.org/users/80765/jonasfovea/) on 2021-08-12**:
The port is correct. When I plug in the board I the device `/dev/ttyACM0` appears just as expected.
While executing the `catkin_make` the board was plugged into my machine.

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-08-12**:
@jonasfovea Thank you for the confirmation. Answer updated.

**Comment by [jonasfovea](https://answers.ros.org/users/80765/jonasfovea/) on 2021-08-12**:
Thanks a lot!
That was a very stupid mistake ^^

Have a great day!